# Drawing Rectangle in AWT is Causing Flickering of the Rectangle to Occur

Tags: java, awt

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why the paddle is flickering when I try to draw it. I know that I could use JFrame, but I am using awt for a specific reason. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Pong extends Applet implements Runnable,KeyListener{

//applet height and width
final int WIDTH = 700;
final int HEIGHT = 500;
Thread thread;
HumanPaddle p1;

//initialize the applet
public void init(){
    this.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    this.addKeyListener(this);
    p1 = new HumanPaddle(1);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

//paints the applet
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    p1.draw(g);
}

//continually updated within the program
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}


public void run() {
    //infinite loop with a error try and catch
    for(;;){

        p1.move();

        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        p1.setUpAccel(true);
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        p1.setDownAccel(true);
    }

}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        p1.setUpAccel(false);
    }
    else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        p1.setDownAccel(false);
    }


}


public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {


}

}
```

and the HumanPaddle class is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HumanPaddle implements Paddle{

//declare variables
double y;
double yVel;
boolean upAccel;
boolean downAccel;
int player;
int x;
final double GRAVITY = 0.94;

public HumanPaddle(int player){
    upAccel = false;
    downAccel = false;
    y = 210;
    yVel = 0;
    if(player == 1)
        x = 20;
    else    
        x = 660;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(x, (int)y, 20, 80);

 }


 public void move() {
    if(upAccel){
        yVel -= 2;
    }
    else if(downAccel){
        yVel += 2;
    }
    else if(!upAccel && !downAccel){
        yVel *= GRAVITY;
    }
    y += yVel;

}


//setters
public void setY(double y){
    this.y = y;
}
public void setYVel(double yVel){
    this.yVel = yVel;
}
public void setUpAccel(boolean upAccel){
    this.upAccel = upAccel;
}
public void setDownAccel(boolean downAccel){
    this.downAccel = downAccel;
}
public void setPlayer(int player){
    this.player = player;
}
public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
}

//getters
public int getY(){
    return (int)y;
}
public double getYVel(){
    return yVel;
}
public boolean getUpAccel(){
    return upAccel;
}
public boolean getDownAccel(){
    return downAccel;
}
public int getPlayer(){
    return player;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}




}
```

Comment: Applet's are not double buffered, hence the flickering; they are also deprecated and no longer supported, so I would advise against using them generally. I would recommend changing tact and using a `JPanel` as base component, as it's double buffered by default. You can then add this to whatever container you want. Have a look at [Custom Painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Thank you, it was just a tutorial I was following that did so. I will definitely look into JPanel, it seems much better!

Answer (score -1):

If you are having this problem, the way I solved it was that I added repaint(), which calls the update method in the paint method. It has to be after when you draw in order so that the recursive loop won't leave that part out. I hope I explained that right, kinda a newby programmer!

Comment: Calling for a repaint in the paint method is not the way to achieve animation. For the actual problem, at best it is an hack.